# How to do a recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, recursive-query

I have a database table looks like this:

```
EVENT_ID TEXT_FRO TEXT_TO
55001              05
55001    05        10
55001    10        15
55001    15        20
55001    20        30
56215    06        11
56215    11        22
```

I need to write a query (or a SP) to produce a result set to list all movements for each distinct event_ID which looks like this:

```
Event ID Movements
55001    05 10 15 20 30
56215    06 11 22
```

How can I do that?

*Edit to simplify the example

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are there any other columns in this table, such as a primary key or a datetime? I ask because how is it known that 28 comes before 27 in your Movements column (tables don't have a default order)?  I'm also confused about the movements of EVENT_ID 56215, as in, what comes next in `05 85 ??`

Comment: Hi Tim, sorry for the ambiguity, the movement is timestamped and that is how we can know the movement order. And I have modified 56215 event, I just made them up and it is a mistake in the data....

Comment: Okay, with this new data, why does EVENT_ID 56215 not have a `null, 06` row?  Which column will have nulls (if any) and is that how we know the first Movement?  Also, will you have data (like before) where a value can occur multiple times for Movement in one row?

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server?

Comment: It is MSSQL 2008. An event does not have to start with a null location. Also yes the event and move back and forth from two locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward if you use a function and a cursor:

```
use tempdb
go

create table tmp (
  EVENT_ID int, 
  TEXT_FRO varchar(10), 
  TEXT_TO varchar(10)
)
go

insert into tmp values
(55001, NULL, '05'),
(55001, '05', '26'),
(55001, '26', '28'),
(55001, '28', '27'),
(55001, '27', '26'),
(55001, '26', '27'),
(55001, '27', '28'),
(55001, '28', '30'),
(55001, '30', '40'),
(56215, '06', '11'),
(56215, '11', '22')
go
```

You have to create a function to assemble the concatenated string:

```
create function fnConcat (@id int) returns varchar(255) as
begin
  declare @rtn varchar(255) = '', @fro varchar(10), @to varchar(10), @cnt int = 1

  declare cr cursor local for
    select TEXT_FRO, TEXT_TO
    from   tmp
    where  EVENT_ID = @id

  open cr
  fetch next from cr into @fro, @to

  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    if @cnt = 1 and @fro is not null
      set @rtn = @rtn + @fro + ' '

    set @rtn = @rtn + @to + ' '

    set @cnt = @cnt + 1
    fetch next from cr into @fro, @to
  end

  close cr
  deallocate cr

  set @rtn = left(@rtn, datalength(@rtn) - 1)

  return @rtn
end
go
```

It is more efficient if you only call the function **one** time per unique EVENT_ID, so we select the `distinct` EVENT_ID in a sub-query:

```
select x.EVENT_ID as [Event ID], dbo.fnConcat(x.EVENT_ID) as Movements
from (
  select distinct EVENT_ID
  from tmp
) as x
go
```

And then cleanup:

```
drop table tmp
go
drop function fnConcat
go
```

This is the result looks like this:

```
Event ID    Movements
----------- ---------------------------
55001       05 26 28 27 26 27 28 30 40
56215       06 11 22
```

Comment: Hi James, your code works fine except when an event moves back to a location where it previously moved from, it will lose this record in the result set. 

For example if the table data looks like: 
insert into tmp values
(55001, NULL, '05'),
(55001, '05', '26'),
(55001, '26', '28'),
(55001, '28', '27'),
(55001, '27', '26'),
(55001, '26', '27'),
(55001, '27', '28'),
(55001, '28', '30'),
(55001, '30', '40')
go

Then the result set will be 
Event ID    Movements
55001       05 26 27 28 30 40

Instead of 

Event ID    Movements
55001       05 26 28 27 26 27 28 30 40

Comment: You didn't provide those details in the original question. I tweaked the function to handle forward and backward movements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive common table expression.

For testing purposes I added a column to the test table that identifies the order of the events in order to be able to identify the first one:

```
create table movements 
(
  event_id   INTEGER,
  text_fro   VARCHAR(10),
  text_to    VARCHAR(10),
  sort_ord   INTEGER
);

insert into movements (event_id, text_fro, text_to, sort_ord)
values
(55001,null,'05',1),
(55001,'05','10',2),
(55001,'10','15',3),
(55001,'15','20',4),
(55001,'20','30',5),
(56215,'06','11',1),
(56215,'11','22',2)
;

with mvt as (
   select m1.event_id as root_id,
          m1.event_id,
          cast(coalesce(m1.text_fro,'') + ' ' + m1.text_to as varchar(8000)) as path,
          m1.text_fro,
          m1.text_to,
          m1.sort_ord
   from movements m1
   where m1.text_fro is null
   or m1.sort_ord = (select min(sort_ord) from movements m2 where m1.event_id = m2.event_id)

   union all 

   select p.root_id,
          c.event_id,
          p.path + ' ' + c.text_to,
          c.text_fro,
          c.text_to,
          c.sort_ord
   from movements c
     join mvt p on p.text_to = c.text_fro
)
select root_id, max(ltrim(path)) as movements
from mvt
group by root_id;
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65937/1)

I'm not sure how to deal with cycles in your event loops though.

Comment: Cycles can be detected by checking the assembled path to determine if the movement has already been processed.  They can be limited by using the `MAXRECURSION` hint, although that requires dynamic SQL if a calculated value is being used (e.g. based on the numbers of rows to be processed).  The question then becomes how to abort the query.  A CLR function might be useful to assert an error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This CLT doesn't work with the cycles though, when I tried to run the CLT query, error throw as The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.